# Calibrating Vasicek model for historical data

Tags: interest-rates, yield-curve, zero-coupon, term-structure

I need to to estimate the parameters of vasicek model to predict the zero curve. 
My database has 4k daily observations of zero rate for 37 maturities. My question is do I have to estimate the model parameters for each maturity ?

Comment: By 37 maturities I understand, that you have got zero curves for 1 year, 2 year and so on.

The "simple" vasicek model models single yield process:
https://victor-bernal.weebly.com/uploads/5/3/6/9/53696137/projectcalibration.pdf

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have zero curves for the last 4000 days. What I'am specifically asking is when it comes to the instantaneous rate that I'll use to calibrate the model i.e r(t) = a +b*r(t-1) + epsilon , can I use the zero rate for 1day maturity considering it's the shortest maturity I've got ? I've seen people in other papers using the overnight interbank rate. @DataAdventurer